# Stanford CoreNLP NER .net gives different output to the java version and the online demo ones

Tags: c#, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am doing NLP NER task and I'm using the Stanford CoreNLP, while trying the .net version I have noticed that the output of .net version is different to the online demo and the java versions(and those 2 are identical).

Let's take an example of "Obama was born on August 4, 1961, at Kapiolani Medical Center for Women and Children in Honolulu, Hawaii, USA." sentence.

Both online demo and java give same output:

The online demo:

[image: the online demo]

The java version:

[image: the java version]

while the C# version gives:

[image: the C# version]

In the java version I import all the NLP package while in the C# version I import only one file and that's here:

```
string path = @"some_path\stanford-ner-2017-06-09\classifiers\english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
CRFClassifier classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions(path);
```

Is that the really reason? if yes, then how can I resolve that issue?

I have noticed that too, the C# version gives better prediction in some words and vice versa.